# Uploading images with blur shadows

Tags: support, images

I wanted to upload this image, which illustrates some answers to a question I asked.

http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/mg262/combined.pdf

As you can see, if I try and upload it as a PDF, the forum software doesn't cope with the blur shadows very well.

[image]

Normally I would actually use imagemagick's convert, and upload as a PNG, but that fails catastrophically here:

[image]

That's ImageMagick 6.6.3-0, invoked via `convert -trim -bordercolor White -density 180 $1 -border 8x8` .

Is there any way to accurately upload images like this?

Comment: The link to the PDF file seems to be broken.

Comment: Whoops. Thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

1. Flatten the image by taking a screen capture of the content;
2. Paste it in an image editor;
3. Crop to size;
4. Upload

This would be the direct/I-have-access-to-an-image-editor way. However, ...

The StackExchange image hosting service IMGUR also allows "online cropping of images".

1. Flatten the image by taking a screen capture of the content;
2. Visit [IMGUR](http://www.imgur.com) and click on Web (or on the Upload button in the top "menu" bar)

   [image]
3. Paste your screen shot from your clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>; you may have to click on that part of the dialog box):

   [image]
4. Check the "Edit" box and hit the "Start Upload" button:

   [image]

   [image]
5. Crop to your liking and save

   [image]
6. Copy the "Direct Link URL" and upload the result using the regular StackExchange image upload service, this time "from the web". This follows that same procedure listed in [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764):

   [image]

   [image]
7. Done

   [image]

It's advised to re-upload the image from IMGUR's default site to the dedicated StackExchange IMGUR hosting service, otherwise the link might turn up dead later. Once you get used to this as an alternative, it's not that complicated.

Comment: FWIW, screen capture doesn't work on my XP box (I've tried several methods), which is why one reason I use convert -- but that's my problem!

Comment: @Mohan [MWSnap](http://www.mirekw.com/winfreeware/mwsnap.html) is a simple little screen capture tool that works on XP.

Comment: @Mohan: What does “XP box” mean?

Comment: @Speravir: PC running Windows XP

Comment: @Mohan: Then the Print-key or much better Alt+Print work. If not, your problem is not TeX related and perhaps serious (test another keyboard). BTW an excellent free screenshot tool is [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/).

Comment: @Speravir MWSnap works great, unlike PrtScrn or the last 3 programs I tried. + I know it's not a TeX-related problem!