# How can I upload an image to be included in a comment?

Tags: support, comments, images

This is a follow-up question to [how can i upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764), this time with regards to comments. The comment-interface seems limited and doesn't support embedding of images, yet some people are able to insert links to images. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

True, comments provide only a limited set of markdown features (actually referred to as mini-markdown) with no convenient image-inclusion technique.

The only way is to insert the image using the way described in [how can i upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764) (that is, in the "Your Answer" box press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or via the GUI), copy the link and then use the hyperlink markdown

```
...see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/<filename>) for more detail...
```