# Printed output of a .tex document

Tags: support

Both in questions as well as in answers I frequently see code (for example an MWE) followed by the printed output that code produces, something I have never managed to achieve. How is this done?

Comment: Not sure if someone has some other workflow, but I think most of us compile the code, take a screenshot and upload the image

Comment: this is pretty much the method i use: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5957/579  there are other methods shown in other answers to that question.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: See [Most efficient workflow for displaying (imgur hosted) output of TeX & friends source?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5955/5764) I use [FSCapture](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=775) myself to snip a crop of the output and paste that in my questions/answers.