# Where are the instructions?

Tags: support, editing, markdown

There used to be instructions on how to format questions, which included such things as it displaying the compiled mwe. Are the instructions still available, and if so, how??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find instructions in the help center: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Furthermore, there's a question mark button at the top right of the editing window, when you write a post. Click it, and you get a help menu where you can click a topic (links, images, lists, code etc.) And if you click on Advanced help, you get a [Markdown editing help overview](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: The cited instructions don't say how to convert the compiled mwe.pdf to the format required by imgur.  Many newbies coming from math.sx expect this output to be shown using MathJax, but tex.sx does *not* do that (for good reasons).  Two answers that tell how are https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5957 and  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237167  Neither is perfect, but I believe I can draft a good, specific answer to cover most single-page instances of such a situation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think both of those are far more complicated than need be, I haven't made a cropped file to upload for years since the site added cut and paste of images. Just select a desired area in the pdf viewer then hit ctrl-v in the stackexchange post.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Well, since I've had problems grabbing a properly delimited screenshot, I've depended on that method, which is reliable.  And it can be explained quite concisely, as I tried to do in my cited answer.  But as that is specific to a particular example, buried among a lot of other answers, and when I needed to find a method myself it took a couple hours of digging, I thought it might be kind to newbies to provide a straightforward method.

Comment: @barbarabeeton many people are not at all familiar with the commandline and tools like pdfcrop. Selecting an area of the screen is something that is very familiar to most users. I think that using pdfcrop is far from straightforward and requires the command line and making and deleting temporary files on the local filesystem. I'd not object to that being mentioned but certainly shouldn't be the first method mentioned, just a fallback if you can't simply paste in the desired view.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Okay, but the instructions on using Markdown don't say anything at all about attaching an output example, and that really should be mentioned, if only to say that an image can be attached using the image icon above the answer box.