# Add directly a PDF image from overleaf to a question or an aswer edit

Tags: discussion, images

When posting a question or an answer on [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com) I often start by creating a MWE with [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com). Then if I want to include the resulting PDF I have to download it to my local system first before inserting it into the post. My question is as follows: is there a way to include the PDF directly from overleaf without download it to my local system?

Comment: Maybe taking a screenshot would be a quicker way.

Comment: it probably isn't possible.  to the best of my knowledge, only .png images are supported.  so if a pdf image can be converted on overleaf to png, then that could be downloaded directly.  might be something to be asked of overleaf.

Comment: I thought it used to be possible, see [this answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2137/17107). But it might be that it is just a [thing of the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316662).

Answer (score 6):

As of now, Stack Exchange only provides **image uploader on all sites** using Imgur's service.

While some SE sites got their customization like Code Snippet (SO, etc), MathJax (Mathematics.SE, etc), embedded YouTube video (SciFi.SE, etc), ABC notation (Music.SE)... but **PDF uploader is not one of them**.

The community of Blender.SE provides [an unofficial way to upload .blend file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting) (maintained by their community instead of SE) since they need the file to reproduce the problem.

However, TeX has simple textual markdown, and it's rendered visually, so... why the hassle of uploading a PDF file when you can just upload an image that is directly shown on the post? :)